"No current event loop in thread 'Thread-1' when using asyncio in Django on staging environment" aioapns
I'm encountering an issue with my Django application, specifically in a method designed to send notifications via Apple Push Notification service (APNs). The method works perfectly in my local environment but fails on the staging server, throwing the error:"There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'."
I am using aioapns for handling APNs notifications and asyncio to manage asynchronous calls. The code involves creating a notification request and attempting to send it through the APNs client. I suspect this may be related to how event loops are handled in different environments or threads.
In my implementation, I first tried to retrieve the current event loop using asyncio.get_event_loop().When that raised a RuntimeError, I created a new event loop with asyncio.new_event_loop() and set it as the current loop. However, this approach doesn't resolve the error when executed in a separate thread, as is common in Django.
Here's a snippet of the relevant code:
def PingDevice(cls, devicetoken, pushmagic):
    print("Start...")
    topic = "com.apple.mgmt.External.ff2ea8ba-350c-4e1d-9a0d-cf8f62c06086"
    cert_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'sign', "PushCert.pem")
    print("devicetoken: ", devicetoken)
    print("pushmagic: ", pushmagic)
    print("cert_content: ", cert_path)

    apns_cert_client = APNs(client_cert=cert_path, use_sandbox=False, topic=topic)
    print(apns_cert_client)

    request = NotificationRequest(
        device_token=base64.b64decode(devicetoken).hex(),
        message={'mdm': pushmagic.decode('utf-8')},
        push_type=PushType.MDM,
        apns_topic=topic
    )
    print("request", request)

    # Get or create the event loop
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f"Creating new event loop: {e}")
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    # Run the notification in the event loop
    try:
        response = loop.run_until_complete(apns_cert_client.send_notification(request))
        response_data = {
            "description": response.description,
            "status": response.status,
            "notification_id": response.notification_id,
            "is_successful": response.is_successful
        }

        if response.is_successful:
            print(f"Notification sent successfully, response: {response_data}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to send notification, response: {response_data}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending notification: {e}")
    finally:
        loop.close()


I expected the notification to be sent without issues, but I received the error message indicating that there is no current event loop in the thread where the method is executed.
Additional Context:
Local Python version: 3.8.20
Staging Python version: 3.8.12
The staging environment is set up to run Django with threading enabled, which may affect how asyncio operates.
I am using aioapns to manage APNs notifications.
Any insights or suggestions on how to properly handle the event loop in this context would be greatly appreciated!
